# Alter table - change the default value of a column

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a column with REAL data type, and I'm trying to write a statement to change the default value to 4.  However, when I use the select * statement to double check, the column is still empty.

```
ALTER TABLE recipes
MODIFY NumberOfServings DEFAULT '4';
```

Comment: The `ALTER` does not update your table. It's for only row that WILL be inserted.

Answer (score 1):

The DEFAULT value is used at INSERT time. It gives a default value to be inserted when you do not provide a value for the column in the INSERT statement.

You may want to update the table, so that all NULL values are replaced by a given value:

```
UPDATE recipes SET NumberOfServings=4 WHERE NumberOfServings IS NULL;
```

You can also specify a value to use when the column is NULL at QUERY time.
This can be done by using the NVL function:

```
SELECT NVL(NumberOfServings,4) FROM recipes;
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm

Comment: I'm trying to change it so every entry is 4 in the entire column when I use the select * statement

Comment: In this case you can use the UPDATE statement above

Answer (score 0):

The default value applies only when you insert new records into the table. It does not update any existing values in the table. Why do you enclose a numeric value in quotes?